# Change Shortcut on MacOS for 'Insert' key

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

**EDIT**
When converting a program with 100+ forms. Some of them have popupmenus with the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key as shortcut. This key does not excists on a Mac Keyboard, or even the Mac OS.

So we need to change all these shortcuts when deploying for mac.

**Solution**

1. Suggested by David Hefferman : When Streaming a Form, loop through all actions and shortcuts and then change the shortcut.
2. Change key handling of new shortcut to map to the old one (in the form). And change the shortcut when the popupmenu is showing, to show the new shortcut.

code

```
TMenuItem = class(FMX.Menus.TMenuItem)
  protected
    procedure ApplyStyle; override;
    procedure DialogKey(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;

TForm = class(FMX.Forms.TForm)
  public
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: System.WideChar; Shift: TShiftState); override;
  end;

 procedure TMenuItem.ApplyStyle;
begin
  inherited;
  //When the popupmenu is shown, make shure that the shortcut is showing the new one
  if self.ShortCut=45 then
    self.ShortCut := 16462; //new shortcut (Ctrl+N)
end;

procedure TMenuItem.DialogKey(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (key = 45) AND (ShortCut = 16462)  then begin //form has passed old shortcut so change it back
    ShortCut:= 45;
    inherited;
    ShortCut := 16462; //revert to new
  end else begin
    inherited;
  end;
  if self.ShortCut=45 then //if the shortcut was still mapped to old shortcut, map to new
    self.ShortCut := 16462;
end;

procedure TForm.KeyDown(var Key: Word; var KeyChar: System.WideChar; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  //new Shortcut is ctrl+N        
  if (key=vkN) AND (ssCtrl in Shift) then begin
    key := 45; //change to the code for insert
    Shift := shift - [ssCTRL]; //remove Ctrl
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Why subclass? Why not just set the property at runtime?

Comment: i have about 100 forms. So I rather add a unit to the interface, then to program changes at runtime.

Comment: All your forms are derived from a common base class?

Comment: Yes, i can use same method to change the function of Dialogkey, but i still have a problem that the 'Ins' key does not excist on MACOS tand shows (45)

Comment: If you have a common base class you can iterate over the menu items, actions etc. after the form has been streamed.

Comment: What method does the streamin gof the form? where should i put this code? EndUpdate? AfterConstruction? Loaded? Trying Loaded now.

Comment: `Loaded` would work. So would the constructor. After you have called the inherited constructor. `AfterConstruction` would work.

Comment: OS X **does** support an "Ins"ert key.  The problem is that (some?) Apple keyboards do not include it or label it differently.  Supplementary question:  Does FireMonkey handle the different conventions for keyboard shortcuts w.r.t Windows vs OS X ?  i.e. standard shortcuts in OS X employ the CMD modifer, not CTRL.  If FireMonkey doesn't re-map these automatically then I suggest you have a bigger problem than simply dealing with the "Insert: key (a problem that OS X users will likely already be familiar with: http://tinyurl.com/qxu4dvy).